# How can I draw a fullscreen background image in WebGL like sketchfab?

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, textures, background-image

I know how to draw models, but I don't know how to draw a fullscreen background image.

I think I should draw it at the zfar of the camera. But I have no idea how to calculate its size...

In sketchfab, it seems the background image can implement the css property`background-size: cover`. And I notice sketchfab do not implement it by css.

I really want to know how to implement this!

[image]

Comment: @Rabbid76 WebGL only.

Comment: @Rabbid76 centered. Just like `background-size: cover`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 If keep its aspect ratio is not difficult, I want to know too. :D

Comment: I know you wanted a solution without using CSS but I don't know why. It's simpler using CSS and unless you're going to do something special (answeryou accepted to does not) then there's really no point

Comment: @gman Because in WebVR, the vr camera can not see the css background image... : -(

Comment: Good point, although BTW you're eventually supposed to be able to use html in WebVR. I have no idea how long until that actually happens though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I draw a fullscreen background image in WebGL like like style `background-size: cover`?

Create a simple shader which draws a texture, without any transformations:

Vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;
varying   vec2 vertPos;

void main()
{
    vertPos     = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2      vertPos;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec2 texCoord = vec2( vertPos.s, -vertPos.t ) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec3 texColor = texture2D( u_texture, texCoord.st ).rgb;
    gl_FragColor  = vec4( texColor.rgb, 1.0 );
}
```

Create a an array buffer, with the 4 corner points of the XY-plane, of the Normalized device space, from (-1, -1) to (1, 1).

```
bufRect = gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufRect );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ] ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
```

Draw the rectangle to the entire canvas, by using the shader. Since you draw on every fragment, you do not need to clear the color plane. But **you have to disable the depth test**.

```
gl.disable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );

var texUnit = 1;
gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureObj );
var tex_loc = gl.getUniformLocation( progBG, "u_texture" );
gl.useProgram( progBG );
gl.uniform1i( tex_loc, texUnit );

var v_attr_inx = gl.getAttribLocation( progBG, "inPos" );
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufRect );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( v_attr_inx, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( v_attr_inx );
gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
gl.disableVertexAttribArray( v_attr_inx );
```

**Enable the depth test and clear the depth buffer**, before you draw the geometry of the scene:

```
gl.clear( gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
.....
```

Note, when you load the texture, then you have to ensure that the width and the height of the texture is a power of 2.

```
var Texture = {};
Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D = function( image, texture, flipY ) {
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    if ( flipY != undefined && flipY == true )
      gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, null );
    return texture;
}
Texture.LoadTexture2D = function( name ) {
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    texture.image = new Image(64,64);
    texture.image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    texture.image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        canvas.width = 512;
        canvas.height = 256;
        var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
        context.drawImage( texture.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
        Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D( canvas, texture, true )
    }
    texture.image.src = name;
    return texture;
}
```

```
textureObj = Texture.LoadTexture2D( "my_background_texture" );
```

See the code snippet:

```js
glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );

function IdentityMat44() {
  var m = new glArrayType(16);
  m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
  m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
  m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
  m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
  return m;
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

var Camera = {};
Camera.create = function() {
    this.pos    = [0, 5, 0.0];
    this.target = [0, 0, 0];
    this.up     = [0, 0, 1];
    this.fov_y  = 90;
    this.vp     = [800, 600];
    this.near   = 0.5;
    this.far    = 100.0;
}
Camera.Perspective = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = t/r; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  =  0;                              m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0;   m[5]  = t; m[6]  =  0;                              m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0;   m[9]  = 0; m[10] = -fn / f_n;                       m[11] = -1;
    m[12] = 0;   m[13] = 0; m[14] = -2 * this.far * this.near / f_n; m[15] =  0;
    return m;
}
Camera.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = mx[0]; m[1]  = my[0]; m[2]  = mz[0]; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = mx[1]; m[5]  = my[1]; m[6]  = mz[1]; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = mx[2]; m[9]  = my[2]; m[10] = mz[2]; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = tx;    m[13] = ty;    m[14] = tz;    m[15] = 1; 
    return m;
} 

var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.attribIndex = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.attribIndex[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( progObj, name );
        }
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.attribIndex[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.UniformLocation = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.unifomLocation[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformI1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1f( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM33 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript) {
      source = "";
      var node = shaderScript.firstChild;
      while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) source += node.textContent;
        node = node.nextSibling;
      }
    }
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : 0;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : 0;
}

var VertexBuffer = {};
VertexBuffer.Create = function( attributes, indices ) {
    var buffer = {};
    buffer.buf = [];
    buffer.attr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++ i ) {
        buffer.buf.push( gl.createBuffer() );
        buffer.attr.push( { size : attributes[i].attrSize, loc : attributes[i].attrLoc } );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i] );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attributes[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    }
    buffer.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    buffer.inxLen = indices.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    return buffer;
}
VertexBuffer.Draw = function( bufObj ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i ) {
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i] );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    }
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i )
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
}

    var Texture = {};
    Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D = function( image, texture, flipY ) {
        gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
        gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
        if ( flipY != undefined && flipY == true )
          gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT );
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, null );
        return texture;
    }
    Texture.LoadTexture2D = function( name ) {
        var texture = gl.createTexture();
        texture.image = new Image(64,64);
        texture.image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        texture.image.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            canvas.width = 512;
            canvas.height = 256;
            var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
            context.drawImage( texture.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
            Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D( canvas, texture, true )
        }
        texture.image.src = name;
        return texture;
    }
   
var ticks = 0;        
function drawScene(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "draw-canvas" );
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    Camera.create();
    Camera.vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    var currentTime = Date.now();   
    var deltaMS = currentTime - startTime;
    ticks = ticks + 1;
        
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    //gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    
    gl.disable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    
    var texUnit = 1;
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureObj );
    var tex_loc = gl.getUniformLocation( progBG, "u_texture" );
    gl.useProgram( progBG );
    gl.uniform1i( tex_loc, texUnit );
    
    var v_attr_inx = gl.getAttribLocation( progBG, "inPos" );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufRect );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( v_attr_inx, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( v_attr_inx );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( v_attr_inx );
    
    // set up draw shader
    ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_projectionMat44", Camera.Perspective() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_viewMat44", Camera.LookAt() );
    var modelMat = IdentityMat44()
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 13.0 ), 0 );
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 17.0 ), 1 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw, "u_modelMat44", modelMat );
    
    // draw scene
    gl.clear( gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufCube );
}

var startTime;
function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( currentTime, intervall ) {
    return Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( currentTime, intervall, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    
function EllipticalPosition( a, b, angRag ) {
    var a_b = a * a - b * b
    var ea = (a_b <= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( a_b );
    var eb = (a_b >= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( -a_b );
    return [ a * Math.sin( angRag ) - ea, b * Math.cos( angRag ) - eb, 0 ];
}

var sliderScale = 100.0
var gl;
var progDraw, progBG;
var bufCube = {};
var bufRect = {};
function sceneStart() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "draw-canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progBG = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "background-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "background-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ] );
      progBG.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progBG, "inPos" );
    if ( progBG == 0 )
        return; 

    progDraw = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ] );
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inPos" );
    progDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inCol" );
    if ( progDraw == 0 )
        return;   

    //textureObj = Texture.LoadTexture2D( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/supermario.jpg" );    
    textureObj = Texture.LoadTexture2D( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/background.jpg" ); 

    bufRect = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufRect );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ] ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // create cube
    var cubePos = [
      -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
      -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0 ];
    var cubeCol = [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ];
    var cubeHlpInx = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 4, 5 ];  
    var cubePosData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; ++ i ) {
      cubePosData.push( cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+1], cubePos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+2] );
    }
    var cubeNVData = [];
    for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < cubeHlpInx.length; i1 += 4 ) {
    var nv = [0, 0, 0];
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) {
        var i = i1 + i2;
        nv[0] += cubePosData[i*3]; nv[1] += cubePosData[i*3+1]; nv[2] += cubePosData[i*3+2];
    }
    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 )
      cubeNVData.push( nv[0], nv[1], nv[2] );
    }
    var cubeColData = [];
    for ( var is = 0; is < 6; ++ is ) {
      for ( var ip = 0; ip < 4; ++ ip ) {
       cubeColData.push( cubeCol[is*3], cubeCol[is*3+1], cubeCol[is*3+2] ); 
      }
    }
    var cubeInxData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; i += 4 ) {
      cubeInxData.push( i, i+1, i+2, i, i+2, i+3 );   
    }
    bufCube = VertexBuffer.Create(
    [ { data : cubePosData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
      //{ data : cubeNVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
      { data : cubeColData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol } ],
      cubeInxData );

    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval(drawScene, 50);
}
```

```html
<script id="background-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    precision mediump float;

    attribute vec2 inPos;
    varying   vec2 vertPos;

    void main()
    {
        vertPos     = inPos;
        gl_Position = vec4( inPos, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="background-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2      vertPos;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    
    void main()
    {
        vec2 texCoord = vec2( vertPos.s, -vertPos.t ) * 0.5 + 0.5;
        vec3 texColor = texture2D( u_texture, texCoord.st ).rgb;
        gl_FragColor  = vec4( texColor.rgb, 1.0 );
    }
</script>  

<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inCol;

varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;

void main()
{
    vertCol       = inCol;
    vec4 modelPos = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    vec4 viewPos  = u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
    gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vertCol;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vertCol.rgb, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<body onload="sceneStart();">
    <canvas id="draw-canvas" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, your explain is really amazing! I hope I can get the point: draw the texture without depth test first, and then draw the models with depth test. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: One more question, what is the usage of `{ alpha: true }` when creating webgl context ?

Comment: @user2331095 You are right, this is absolutely unnecessary, because there is no blending. I first thought on another solution, which I rejected finally. I removed this part from the answer.

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero ! :D

Comment: @user2331095 One last thing. The depth buffer should be cleared **before** drawing the scene and **after** drawing the background.

Comment: `alpha: true` is the default so passing it or not will not make a difference.

Comment: @Rabbid76: is there any special reason (maybe performance or something else..?) because you didn't used CLAMP_TO_EDGE?

Comment: @deblocker No, there is no special reason. Since the background image is stretch to the full screen, it makes no difference.